# Anaglyph or stereo views and picking

Tags: three.js

I tested the anaglyph effect. And my picking no more work properly.
Is this normal ?
If yes is there a way to have the picking working when using 3D effects ?

Comment: The anaglyph effect should not have any affect on picking because it is only an effect. But instead of trying to pick on the red or the blue object, you should try picking somewhere in the middle of the two. That's where the actual object is. If it still not working try creating a fiddle or post some code with the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. In fact it works when picking somewhere in the middle of the two images. But I had glasses last week to see the anaglyph and when clicking on the 3D object it was not working...  So I will test again with glasses... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tested again and I found that the separation between the eyes was too big in my case. With a smaller value the image is nicer and the click more accurate and the picking works.

Comment: May I ask how you changed the eye separation. did you change the code in AnaglyphEffect.js?

Comment: Yes I changed the code. I have old red-green glasses. I verified that it was not a problem of color. Then I tried the eye separation. I have no clean solution...

Answer (score 0):

I said that the picking works but it is not true. By reducing the eye separation I reduced the difference between the 2 images. So I reduced the problem. As the mouse pointer is not rendered in green and red it is not possible to pick with it.