# Three.js - Stereo Effect - Picking

Tags: three.js

I had the possibility to test the Stereo Effect on a TV using side by side images. It works fine.
The only problem is when I want to pick something : the picked point is wrong.

To debug I draw the line eye-picked_point.
I picked a point in 3D mode (with the glasses and the TV in 3D mode).
Then I stopped the TV 3D mode to see the 2 three.js images with the lines eye-picked_point.
Here is the result : the picked point is not in the blue face :
[image]

Maybe it is important to say that the html page is like this :
- First there is a  line to write debug informations.
- Under this line there is a line of buttons.
- Under the buttons there is the three.js view.

The picking works well in normal mode.

Should the picking work in 3D ?
Does it work for you ?

Comment: this should be informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676450/anaglyph-or-stereo-views-and-picking

Comment: I remember my question and your explanation. It works with anaglyph. With stereo effect I added a slider to dynamically change the eye separation. So the rendering is perfect. But the picking does not work : it should be on the same target point in the 2 points of view. But it is not the same point  and at the wrong place. The question is : does it work for somebody ? Or am I doing a classical mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer : it is not possible to pick in 3D using the mouse pointer because the mouse pointer is a 2D thing over the 2 side by side images. It is not something that is seen in 3D.